# Monospaced bitmap programmer’s font at big sizes (14pt+)

Tags: fonts

I would really like to try bitmapped font - like, proggy - but I always use 14pt or bigger fonts. Is there any monospaced bitmapped font of that size? I couldn't find any. Seems like programmers have good eyes... unlike me.

Yes I need a bitmap font, there're lots of TrueType ones and they're not a problem to find. But it seems there're no large bitmap fonts.

Comment: Do you need a bitmap font? There are many good non-bitmap mono-spaced fonts out there that look good at 14pt.

Comment: Yes I need a bitmap font. I can easily find non-bitmap ones.

Comment: A long time ago I converted the "9x18" bitmap Linux font to TTF to use in Mac OS X. I don't remember the arcane incantations I used to do that (I can dig them up from my backups if you're interested) but here's the end result. You should only use it at 18 pixel height, of course (which might be a different "pt" number, depending on your OS.) https://mega.nz/#!IkoiRToK!bc7t_8qmOMh3uLQxSp8UgTluzritifpS5Zef-Z7I1Hc

Comment: Also Monaco is not bad with anti-aliasing turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following bitmapped fonts:

[Proggy Fonts](http://www.proggyfonts.com/index.php?menu=download)
[Dina Programming Font](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Jibz/Dina/index.html)
[PixelCarnage](http://www.dafont.com/pixelcarnage.d870)
[Terminus font](http://fractal.csie.org/~eric/wiki/Terminus_font)

Keep in mind that bitmap fonts are very precise but don't scale.

Comment: Proggy and Dina do not have 14pt. PixelCarnage too, and is too bad. But the Terminus font hack with bitmaps embedded into TrueType seems to do the trick. Not a perfect one, though, but it seems there's no hope, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

IBM3270 font is monospaced bitmap. Looks great at 14.

http://codedwarf.com/pcsansi.fon

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @amrox, do you actually need a bitmap font, or just a fixed width font? some of the complete typefaces are nice just for their italics (because faux-italics suck). Many of the fonts below look best with sub-pixel rendering enabled.

- [Anonymous](http://www.ms-studio.com/FontSales/anonymous.html) - TT version of a bitmap font
- [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) - knockoff of MS Consolas, Inconsolata doesn't have great italics
- [Consolas](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22e69ae4-7e40-4807-8a86-b3d36fab68d3&displaylang=en) - also nice, complete typeface with bolds and italics
- [Droid Sans Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_%28font%29) - Very nice, lacks a slashed 0 and you have to get it sneakily
- [Deja Vu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) - Open-sauce reasonable, default GNOME fixed width, I think.
- [Liberation Sans](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/) - Nice, also open-sauce, made by the same font designer as Droid font
- [BP Mono](http://www.dafont.com/bpmono.font) - Free, missing many glyphs
- Monaco - Available in OSX
- Andale Mono - was part of IE 5, also in OS X, part of [Core Font pack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/corefonts/files/)

Answer (score -1):

Anonymous
MProFont
ProFont
Sheldon

Comment: Bitmap font? 14+?

Comment: Profont has a 15 I believe.